# Hatespeech Detection in R plain text

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I have a column in my R dataset that has been filled in through plain/free text.

I'd like to be able to search this column for any sort of hate speech, I know there already exist sentiment analysis but I was wondering if there was a hate speech specific one?

Comment: Probably not, it does not make sense to write a function limited to "hate" ... I'd think more appropriate would be a function that looks for sentiment stuff, and you (the user) feed a dictionary of sorts that includes hate-like speech in it, that way the function can also be used for other types of speech, too. Has your research looked into [`nlp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NLP/index.html)? (This question is likely to be closed since it is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as asking for libraries/tutorials. Please improve it if you'd like more help.)

Comment: I'm just curious, what's a definition for a *hate speech*?

Comment: @PoGibas, No formal definition exists but there is a consensus that it is speech that targets disadvantaged social groups in a manner that is potentially harmful to them. (Jacobs and Potter 2000; Walker 1994). More info in [Automated Hate Speech Detection and the Problem of Offensive Language](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04009). www.hatebase.org has a lexicon behind an API that is free for academic use. No R interface. There is a [github page](https://github.com/t-davidson/hate-speech-and-offensive-language) with the article that contains the lexicons as well, but these are 2 years old.

Comment: btw, the lexicon package also has a profanity_racist table. You might want to look into that as well.